# Is it possible to determine the current position when iterating an ICollection?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-2.0, foreach, icollection

I have the following code:

```
foreach(string reelid in unValidatedFeedersOnMachine.Keys)
{
    _sqlString.Append("CompID = '").Append(reelid).Append("' ");
}
```

I need to add in that loop on each iteration `.Appened("or ")` except the last one.

Any idea how i can know when i located on the last iteration here?

Comment: Minor note; if each key (`reelid`) is known to be a safe value (from private config data etc) then this may be fine - but **do not** use concatenation if there is *any chance* a user could have influenced them - perhaps by editing the HTML of a FORM. Otherwise this is a SQL injection attack risk.

Comment: @ Marc Gravell:Those values come from automatic machine , no chance that someone can influence the values .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do it the other way around - treating the first as the exception is simpler:

```
bool first = true;
foreach(string reelid in unValidatedFeedersOnMachine.Keys)
{
   if(first) {first = false;}
   else {_sqlString.Append(" or ";}
    _sqlString.Append("CompID = '").Append(reelid).Append("' ");
}
```

or in .NET 4.0 just use:

```
string s = string.Join(" or ",
           from key in unValidatedFeedersOnMachine.Keys
           select "CompID = '" + reelid + "'");
```

or even better, if this is SQL - switch to `IN`...

```
string s = "CompID IN (" + string.Join(","
           from key in unValidatedFeedersOnMachine.Keys
           select "'" + reelid + "'") + ")";
```

Comment: (note that I'm assuming in the above that the `reelid` is injection-safe - i.e. it is coming from a trusted source; that may be an invalid assumption)

Answer (score 4):

What about doing all in one line ?

```
string query = string.Join(" or ", unValidatedFeedersOnMachine.Keys.Select(x => "CompID = '" + x + "'").ToArray())
```

**P.S.**
If you're targeting .net 4.0, you can skip the `.ToArray()`

Comment: @Night Walker: well, then unfortunately this code is not so useful in your case. BTW, you should say/tag your question to indicate you're in .net 2.0, because it's becoming somewhat infrequent as requirement...

Answer (score 0):

I tend to do this

```
var _sqlString = new StringBuilder();
foreach(string reelid in unValidatedFeedersOnMachine.Keys) {                     
    if(_sqlString.ToString().Length != 0) {
        _sqlString.Appened(" or ")
    }
    _sqlString.Append("CompID = '").Append(reelid).Append("' ");
}
```

Comment: you can just check `StringBuilder.Length`, without `ToString()`